# Can neo4j link nodes between graphs

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and would like to know if it's possible to directly link a node from one graph to one or more nodes on another graph.

I have one core graph with thousands of other graphs. Each core node may link to other graphs, and nodes on that graph may link to other graphs or nodes on other graphs, including nodes on the core graph.

I know I can put all the nodes into one graph, but I would prefer to do it as described above.

Thanks!
Rein

Comment: AFAIK the official stance on this is that everything goes in one graph. That makes sense, given that if two nodes are connected then they are part of the same graph by definition. You can only have two completely independent graphs by running two separate instances of Neo4j and then - of course - they cannot be related.

Comment: What is the difference between your graphs, i.e., what makes them different graphs as opposed to different parts of the same graph? Are you thinking in terms of storage, as in database sharding, or are is it a conceptual distinction?

Answer (score 1):

You have only one graph in a single neo4j instance. You can store your "core graph" and all other graphs as one large unconnected network.